# Plot numpy rec array with date

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I read pickled numpy array with this structure:

```
>>> h.shape
(256,)
>>> h[:10]
rec.array([(datetime.date(2011, 1, 2), 1, -3, 1014),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 3), 3, -6, 1016),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 4), 0, -9, 1023),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 5), 1, -6, 1023),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 6), 3, -2, 1026),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 7), 2, -1, 1029),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 8), -1, -1, 1027),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 9), -1, -2, 1025),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 10), -1, -2, 1025),
       (datetime.date(2011, 1, 11), 3, 3, 1020)], 
      dtype=[('date', '|O4'), ('high', '|i1'), ('low', '|i1'), ('pres', '<i2')])
```

and can't find how to plot it with matplotlib. I tried to use `plt.plot_date(...)` but on any combination I get error. Can someone point me to right direction how to plot simple line graph with X-axis as date and Y-axis any other value from this array, let's say `pres` labeled data?

Comment: does this work [date_demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html) and also this [date_index_formatter](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_index_formatter.html)?

Comment: Ah, right... I forgot about view property of recarray. Thanks!

Comment: So then did that answer your question?  If so you should add what you did as an answer asnd accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `h` is a [`numpy.recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html#numpy.recarray) you can achieve the basic plotting by using

```
plt.plot_date(h.date, h.pres, linestyle='-', marker=None)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate() # Optional; included to format x-axis for dates
```

Further customization might be needed for the plot to look the way you want it.
[image]